# I can't print keys and values in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a data structure that I got from this code.

```
my $name = $data->{Instances}->[0]->{Tags};
```

That data structure looks like this

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'Key' => 'Name',
        'Value' => 'fl-demo'
      },
      {
        'Value' => 'FL',
        'Key' => 'state'
      }
    ];
```

I'm trying to print the keys and values with this

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %$name) {
my $value = $name->{$key};
print "$key  => $value\n";
}
```

I'm getting

```
Not a HASH reference at ./x.pl line 19.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags are returned as an array, not a hash. So you're looking at doing something like this, instead, to iterate over them:

```perl
foreach my $tag (@$name) {
    my $key = $tag->{Key};
    my $val = $tag->{Value};
    print "$key => $val\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on a previous answer:

- `$name` is a reference to an array containing references to hashes.
- `@$name` *and* `@{$name}` *(equivalent representations)* refer to the array that `$name` references.
- `${$name}[0]` *and* `$name->[0]` *(equivalent representations)* refer to the first hash in the array referenced by `$name`.
- `${$name}[0]{'Key'}`, `$name->[0]->{'Key'}`, etc. *(equivalent representations)* refer to `'Key'`'s hash value in the first hash in the array referenced by `$name`.

As such, the following would iterate over all array and hash elements:

```
foreach my $hashref ( @{$name} )
{
    foreach my $key ( sort(keys(%{$hashref})) )
    {
        printf("%s => %s\n",$key,$hashref->{$key});
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

*Or*, more compactly (and arguably unreadably):

```
printf("%s\n",join("\n", map {
    my $h = $_;
    join(', ', map { sprintf('%s=%s',$_,$h->{$_}) } sort(keys(%{$h})) );
} @{$name} ));
```

Comment: `$name->@*` would be the postfix/arrow notation equivalent of `@{$name}`. /// No idea why you used "ish" in two places. There's no "ish" about it.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure dump of variable `$name` indicates that you have array reference.

You can use loop to output the data of interest, do not forget to dereference `$name` variable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $name = [
        {
            'Key' => 'Name',
            'Value' => 'fl-demo'
        },
        {
            'Value' => 'FL',
            'Key' => 'state'
        }
    ];
    

say "$_->{Key} = $_->{Value}" for @$name;
```

Output

```
Name = fl-demo
state = FL
```